# How to apply a patch in Android studio? I am using Subversion

Tags: android, svn, android-studio, patch

I am using subversion in Android studio.  I had code changes I need to save for later(just like a shelveset).  I have created a patch using the following steps.
Right click on project --> Subversion --> Commit Directory --> Create Patch(Second option in the dropdown where "Commit" is the first option).  I have the patch file now and I need a way to apply it to my project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To apply a patch, select VCS (Main Menu) | Apply patch.
Reference: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/applying-patches.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't see in IntelliJ IDEA / Android Studio's documentation any mention that it supports `svn patch`. I guess that you should use an external client.

Comment: Android studio allows me to create a patch.  I am assuming there must be a way to apply that patch.  I am not sure though.

Comment: @arun8 just check the IDE's interface. It either has such command or not.